# jQuery (or regular Javascript) execute function when page is loaded AFTER back button is pressed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've seen this on a lot of websites, but I can't figure out exactly how to do it:

When a function is executed, the URL changes to whatever.com/page/#something and then when that url is accessed, the function is executed again. I know how to make that work when the page is first loaded, but I can't figure out how to make the function occur again when the "back" button is pressed.

(e.g. if I have a tabbed system set up, I start on site.com/#tab1, go to site.com/#tab2, and click the back button so that tab 1 shows up on the page again)

How does that work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to look into [history management](http://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+history+management&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a) in Javascript.  If you aren't using the browser's built-in functionality to maintain history - which is how the back and forward buttons work - you'll need to do a bit of work yourself.

jQuery has several [plugin options](http://plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/history) to help you out.  [hashchange](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/ba-jquery-hashchange-plugin) for example, looks to provide the event you're looking for with an onhashchange event added for browsers that don't have it implemented yet.

Comment: +1 Another plugin I've had recommended to me (haven't actually used it yet, but I trust my source): http://tkyk.github.com/jquery-history-plugin/